# General query: IBM MQ event subscribe option

Tags: ibm-mq

I am writing one application in java, where if there is any event created in event queue in IBM-MQ e.g. queue manager events queue(SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT)

How to get notification, if my java app is subscribed for event notification, if there is any event in event queue(SYSTEM.ADMIN.QMGR.EVENT), rather than polling event queue continuously from java app.

My application will already be running, its purpose will be to scan the event queue, and if any new event comes then notify internally. Basically I wanted to subscribe to event queue for any new event.

Comment: You could trigger start your application when a message arrives on the queue. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi, No my application will already be running, its purpose will be to scan the event queue, and if any new event comes then notify internally. Basically I wanted to subsribe to event queue for any new event.

Comment: So you want to use an asynchronous get instead of a polling synchronous get? Forget what it's called in Java - onMessage?

Comment: Yes, asynchronous get I want instead of polling it continuously.

Comment: Cool - OK. Are you using JMS to write your application or Java classes?

Comment: Hi Morag , We are fine with both ways i.e. JMS or Java Classes./

Comment: You don't need to poll if you use "get with wait".

Comment: There is an example of using onMessage in JMS in the MQ supplied sample in jms\samples\interactive\SampleConsumerJava.jave - have you looked at that?

Comment: Thanks Morag Hughson,
I came to know about sample program : amqsevta.c for event subscription  from link : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=monitoring-sample-program-monitor-instrumentation-events-multiplatforms

Thanks for JMS I will try the /opt/mqm/samp/jms/samples/JmsConsumer.java if it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that if you are using async waits, then the main process needs to be running so that the application doesn't stop, and that it needs to sleep to yield the processor to the wait.

Take a look at the async path for this JMS 2.0 sample - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/93dbc500e4088db3d88099261da420c4b75b7613/amqp-qpid/qpid-standard/src/main/java/com/ibm/mq/samples/jms/qpid/GetJMS20.java

The core of which is

```java
  private void getAsync() {
    JMSConsumer mc = createConsumer();
    mc.setMessageListener(msg -> {
      this.msgListener(msg);
    });
  }

  private void msgListener(Message msg) {
    logger.info("Reading message");
    processMessage(msg);
  }
```